# Koch's "Extendible functions"

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

For more than a year now, I have been looking for a copy of the following CICMA Concordia preprint :

Author : Helmut Koch
Title : Extendible functions
Preprint, CICMA Concordia University Department of Mathematics preprint, 1990.

I tried to locate a copy at the Fields Institute and the University of Toronto libraries, without success.  I have also written to Concordia, again without success.  So I will be very very grateful to anyone who can make a copy (electronic or paper) available to me.  My email address is mylastname@gmail.com.

Comment: why not just ask the author himself? (last name @ mathematik.hu-berlin.de)

Comment: Done, but I have very little hope of getting a reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally have a copy of Koch's *Extendible functions*, thanks to Sazzad Ali Biswas of the University of Hyderabad, who had got it in Berlin from Ernst-Wilhelm Zink.

Needless to say, I'm willing to share it with anyone who is interested.